# Worth a t(h)inker’s...?

Tags: riddle, word, steganography, word-game

> Reward will be waiting, deliver! delay? 
>   The era of puzzling starts now, yes, today! 
>   Some time needs some spending, go tinker away. 
>   That green tick will never decay!

Comment: Is the title's "t(h)inker's" a hint towards finding hidden letters we can add in the puzzle?

Comment: @DavidFoong, no, it was and is hinting though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could be barking up completely the wrong tree, but is it a coincidence that

> several of the words in the riddle are also meaningful words when written backwards?

Namely:

> **Reward** will be waiting, **deliver**! delay?
>  The **era** of puzzling starts **now**, yes, today!
>  Some **time** needs some spending, go **tinker** away.
>  That green tick will never decay!

Giving the following words:

> drawer, reviled, are, won, emit, reknit.

Interestingly,

> the last two of these rhyme, while the middle two could be alphanumeric symbols (R, 1).

Also, the words can be put together in order to give

> REWARD (again) as an acrostic:
>
>  REKNIT
>  EMIT
>  WON
>  ARE
>  REVILED
>  DRAWER

So maybe the final answer is

> REWARD (which also fits with the idea/theme spotted by David Foong in [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63270/5373).

(Thanks to @Drt for help with the last part!)

Comment: maybe an rot13(nantenz v frr qnerqrivy)

Comment: @OnlyF I just spotted something else and edited.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor    I strongly suspect that the answer is "REWARD"   You seem to be so close that I hate to post an answer that is actually yours to take credit for.

Comment: @OnlyF I've made a small edit as suggested by Dr t. Any joy?

Comment: Yep, that's it, no more delay, you've earned that "tick which won't decay" :)

Comment: Filling the answer out on the dots in the title reveals a hidden question, with this being my first riddle which was trying to be a bit harder to solve, any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Reputation

Reward will be waiting, deliver! delay?

> When you answer the puzzle correctly, you will gain a reward: internet points. I should mention at this point that I did not understand any of the steganography.

The era of puzzling starts now, yes, today!

> Another clue about puzzling

Some time needs some spending, go tinker away.

> In order to solve this puzzle, you will have to spend time and tinker with it.

That green tick will never decay!

> You won't lose the reputation you gain (unless you put it on bounties or piss off someone).

Comment: Good job on nearly solving it using only the riddle tag, which was one of the intended solving strategies (the "t(h)inker" hint, was meant to point towards both the fact that the riddle could be solved in two ways, both ways supporting each other off course, and one of the steganography words)

Comment: For the hints, in your first one you've got the gist, but the reference to the answer was missed, the second one is purposely referencing this website (where green ticks are rewarded), your third and fourth clue explanations are pretty good, the "won't decay" bit is meant to point to the "honour of the green tick" type of reward.